# Component re-renders wierdly on state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

My component with a simple MapBox gets re-rendered wierdly on every state change that has nothing to do with the component? Any idea how to prevent this?

It does not happen if I do not add the `data` prop to the second argument of `useEffect`, but I need this to re-render on an actual data change..

**The map component:**

```
const getMap = () => {
    return new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: 'mapContainer',
        style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v9',
        center: [7.32, 60.44],
        zoom: 6,
    })
};
const Map = (props) => {
  const { data } = props
  if (data['features'] != null) {
        useEffect(() => {
            const map = getMap();

            map.on('load', function () {

                map.addSource('malls', {
                    type: "geojson",
                    data: data,
                    cluster: true,
                    clusterMaxZoom: 14, 
                    clusterRadius: 50 
                });

            });
        }, [data]); //

  }
  return (
        <div style={style} id="mapContainer" />
  );
}
```

Comment: React component should return JSX. Your `Map` doesn't return anything

Comment: @hindmost It returns the map container. Updated my code so you can see.

Comment: Only use hooks at the top level of your functional components; do not put them inside conditionals. Try moving the conditional inside your hook. The hook needs to be called on every render, otherwise React will lose the context for your hook. Not using conditionals is one of the primary [rules of hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-overview.html#rules-of-hooks).

Comment: @RossAllen Thank you for that. I actually removed the whole conditional statement as it is not necessary. It still seems to re-render.

Comment: @vemund Could you explain more what's happening now that you don't expect? This component is re-rendering when you don't expect it to?

Comment: You can wrap a functional component in [`React.memo`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) to ensure it re-renders only when its props change.

Comment: Although as stated in the React docs, `React.memo` should be used as a performance optimization and not a guarantee that re-renders will be prevented. If you want that guarantee, you can switch to using a class.

Comment: When I click for example a button that changes some state in the parent, the child component is re-rendered. The state is not passed to the child. What should happen is if the `data` prop is changed, the component should re-render. It does. But it also re-renders on any other changes!

Comment: @RossAllen Thanks! Tested this, but it still re-renders. Might it be because a state change is happening in the parent, the whole parent component re-renders, so the Map also does?

Comment: @vemund Yes, the children would also be re-rendered. If you want to guarantee this component is re-rendered only at specific times, you should switch to a class and implement `shouldComponentUpdate`.

Comment: @RossAllen I have created a repo that shows the issue: https://codesandbox.io/s/rjq7j5x6jq

I have tried to convert to a class, but I still have the same issue.

Comment: Because you were creating the `geojson` object inside the parent's `render` function, a new object was being passed down on every render. I moved that outside `render` and implemented `shouldComponentUpdate` on the `Map` component, and now it doesn't re-render: https://codesandbox.io/s/w7ql22y14l

Answer (score 1):

Hooks should always be called outside conditionals, as mentioned in the [Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-overview.html#rules-of-hooks). You can move your hook to the top-level and move the conditional inside the hook.

```
const Map = (props) => {
  const { data } = props
  useEffect(() => {
    if (data['features'] != null) {
      const map = getMap();
      map.on('load', function () {
        map.addSource('malls', {
          type: "geojson",
          data: data,
          cluster: true,
          clusterMaxZoom: 14, 
          clusterRadius: 50 
        });
      });
    }
  }, [data]);

  return (
    <div style={style} id="mapContainer" />
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this still does not help the wierd re-rendering.. I actually removed the conditionals, as it was not necessary.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of writing it as a function, you should use a class and implement the [`shouldComponentUpdate`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) function.

Comment: Trying to avoid class.

Comment: Both `function` and `class` are legal ways to define a component.

Comment: actually, if you are using hooks you aren't trying to avoid classes, you just **can't** use classes.